# orbeon form builder : get call javascript method after powerfull save click?

Tags: orbeon

i tried to search in xml . but i havnt got solution. after clicking powerful save button,form data is saved in db. call a javascript method after this event. Is there any solution for this problem. i googled for many times.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. Could you show parts of the Xforms code ?

Comment: Something like `navigate('javascript:myJavaScriptFunction()')` in your process should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
navigate('javascript:myJavaScriptFunction()')
```

in your process should work.